# FPC connector to DIP

Tags: pcb, connector, fpc

I have a board which is something like this:
[image]
(available on [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/0-5mm-To-1-2mm-Pin-Pitch-Adapter-PCB-FPC-Board-2-0-3-5-inch-TFT-LCD-SMD-To-DIP-H-/141213193244))

I know I have to buy a socket, but how do I solder the connector onto the board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You solder it with steady hands.

> Its just the solder holding it in place?

Solder would be enough to hold the connector, if you are gentle with it and don't yank it around too much. After all, that's how the FPC connector on the other end of the cable is attached to its board. You can also add a drop of epoxy or hot melt glue to help secure the connector.

Keep in mind that this board is only a kludging aid. In production boards, there are additional large SMT pads on each end of the connector to hold it down more securely.

Comment: My board is 26 pin. Will a 40 pin still be okay if I have a 26 pin cable?( a 26 pin connector should be solderable correct?)

Comment: Pitch is about the only thing that matters.  Fewer pins is okay.

Comment: So I can use a 40 pin socket soldered and still have only 26 pin cable? Or is it better to solder a 26 pin connector and sacrifice a few pin to the right and use a 26 pin cable? Which would be better(The cable is 26 pin since my board is 26 pin)